# How to loop VBA function through multiple rows rather than hard code cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 functions:

- One converts height in feet and inches over to metres.
- One converts weight in stones and pounds over to kilograms.
- One calculates the BMI by dividing the weight by height squared.

The problem is, my functions read values from exact cells and place the calculated values into exact cells, which means I can't repeat the calculations for every row below.

See this screenshot:

[image: BMI Calculator Data]

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Const KgRate As Double = 0.45359237     'number of kg in one pound
Const PoundsInStone As Integer = 14     'number of pounds in one stone

Const InchesInFeet As Integer = 12      'number of inches in one foot
Const CmsInInch As Double = 2.54        'number of centimetres in an inch

Public weightInKilograms As Double

Public finalHeight As Double

**' FUNCTION 1**
Public Function heightInMetres()

Dim numberOfFeet As Integer
Dim numberOfInches As Integer
Dim heightInInches As Integer
Dim heightInCms As Integer

numberOfFeet = Range("C4").Value
numberOfInches = Range("C5").Value

heightInInches = (numberOfFeet * InchesInFeet) + (numberOfInches)
heightInCms = heightInInches * CmsInInch
finalHeight = heightInCms / 100

Range("C7") = finalHeight

End Function

**' FUNCTION 2**
Public Function weightInKilos()

Dim stonesEntered As Integer
Dim poundsEntered As Double
Dim stonesToPounds As Double

stonesEntered = Range("C10").Value
poundsEntered = Range("D10").Value

stonesToPounds = stonesEntered * PoundsInStone

weightInKilograms = ((stonesToPounds + poundsEntered) * KgRate)

Range("E10") = weightInKilograms

End Function

**' FUNCTION 3**
Public Function calculateBMI()

Dim BMI As Double

BMI = weightInKilograms / (finalHeight ^ 2)

Range("F10") = BMI

End Function

**' MAIN PROCEDURE**
Public Sub BMICalculator()

heightInMetres
weightInKilos
calculateBMI

End Sub
```

1) What is the **simplest** way to repeat the weight and BMI calculations for the 3 rows below week 1 (which is row 10 in Excel)?

2) Is it possible to (simply) run the code continuously, e.g. as soon as I update the height and weight cells, the calculations are redone?

3) If there are any (simple) enhancements to the code you can suggest, please do. :-)

Thanks in advance,

Pete

Comment: Add some arguments to your functions and then use them as you would a normal function, e.g. `=heightInMetres(a1,b1)`.

Answer (score 3):

I've changed one of your functions here, if you can follow it you should have no problem converting the others:

```
Public Function heightInMetres(numberOfFeet As Integer, numberOfInches As Integer)

 Dim heightInInches As Integer
 Dim heightInCms As Integer

 heightInInches = (numberOfFeet * InchesInFeet) + (numberOfInches)
 heightInCms = heightInInches * CmsInInch
 finalHeight = heightInCms / 100

 heightInMetres = finalHeight

End Function
```

So now, just enter the following into the cell eg. C7:

`=heightinmetres(C4,C5)`

Where the number of feet are in C4 and inches in C5 (in your example)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Changed the other functions and now I can use them directly in Excel, though my intention was to learn as much VBA as possible and so do it all via a Macro.. but I guess that would be too complex??

Comment: Part of learning to program is learning the best methods to achieve the desired outcome. Given your 3 requirements in your question (and particularly in regards to part 2) - the in-cell UDF (user defined function) is the easiest and simplest way to do it.